# null pointer when trying to set unique request id on gremlin query using `with`

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to set a unique requestId on a gremlin query as outlined in the [Neptune best practise](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/best-practices-gremlin-java-set-query-id.html).

But when I do so, I get a null pointer exception on code that works fine without it.

I'm using the 3.4.2 Gremlin client driver, Java 11, and the unit test is executing against a test container running tinkerpop/gremlin-server:3.4.1

Here's my code:

```
            GraphTraversalSource g = factory.getReadOnlyTraversal();

            return g.with(Tokens.REQUEST_ID, UUID.randomUUID()).V(group.getId()).
                    out("discussing").
                    project("id", "topic", "comments").
                    by(T.id).
                    by("topic").
                    by(__.in("commenting_on").order(Scope.local).
                        project("id", "text", "timestamp", "user").
                        by(T.id).by("text").by("timestamp").
                        by(__.in("is_commenting").valueMap(true)).fold()
                    )
                    .toStream()
                    .map(discussionBuilder::from)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

and here's the stack trace:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:412)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:2044)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet.one(ResultSet.java:119)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.hasNext(ResultSet.java:171)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:178)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:165)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:140)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:125)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal.nextTraverser(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:106)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.processNextStart(RemoteStep.java:80)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:128)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:38)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:204)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.forEachRemaining(Traversal.java:265)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at com.yooblr.yooblrweb.domain.discussions.repositories.GremlinDiscussionsRepositoryImpl.getDiscussions(GremlinDiscussionsRepositoryImpl.java:54)
    at com.yooblr.yooblrweb.domain.discussions.repositories.GremlinDiscussionsRepositoryImplTest.whenGettingDiscussions(GremlinDiscussionsRepositoryImplTest.java:70)
    at com.yooblr.yooblrweb.domain.discussions.repositories.GremlinDiscussionsRepositoryImplTest.multiple(GremlinDiscussionsRepositoryImplTest.java:38)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:221)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:198)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinSaslAuthenticationHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:124)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinSaslAuthenticationHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketClientHandler.channelRead0(WebSocketClientHandler.java:89)
...
```

Same issue happens when I try to set a query timeout:

```
return g.with(Tokens.ARGS_SCRIPT_EVAL_TIMEOUT, 500L).V(group.getId()).
```

Comment: Just to confirm - you are seeing this issues with Gremlin Server and TinkerGraph as well as with Neptune?

Comment: yes.  I just confirmed by adding `.with(Tokens.REQUEST_ID, UUID.randomUUID())` to another unit test that is executing against `tinkerpop/gremlin-server:3.4.1` docker image via test container.. it has failed with the same exception

Comment: Hi again. Just to confirm I was able to reproduce what you saw using Gremlin client and server at the 3.4.1 level. Needs more investigation but wanted to pass that along.

Comment: One more update - still looking into this but I was able to verify that with a 3.4.2 client and a 3.4.3 Gremlin Server it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality was introduced in Apache TinkerPop version 3.4.2. You need both the client and the server to be at the 3.4.2 level (or higher) in order for this to work. Amazon Neptune currently supports Apache TinkerPop at the 3.4.1 level. Once 3.4.2 is supported everything should work. Sorry for any confusion the documentation may have caused.

Comment: thanks Kelvin, the confusing thing is that it was Neptune's own documentation that informed me of this feature; one that the version didn't support! I will give them some feedback including a link to this question.

Comment: that page, linked above, no longer exists on the amazon documentation.